# Calling a char equivalent function with integer in c++ using Function Overloading

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I am overloading a function it just prints the value which it received as an argument .  Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void show(int c)
{
    cout<<"Int C : "<<c<<endl;
}
void show(char c)
{
    cout<<"char C : "<<c<<endl;
}
void show(float c)
{
    cout<<"Float C : "<<c<<endl;
}
void show(string c)
{
    cout<<"String C : "<<c<<endl;
}
void show(const char* c)
{
    cout<<"char *C : "<<c<<endl;
}
main()
{
    string s("Vector");
    show(25);
    show('Z');
    show("C++");
    show("Hello");
    show(4.9f);
    show(s);
}
```

Here show(65) calls the integer function.

**Is there any possibility that I can simply call show(65) to print the ASCII equivalent value 'A' i.e calling show(char) without calling show(int)**

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any possibility that I can simply call show(65) to print the
>   ASCII equivalent value 'A' i.e calling show(char) without calling
>   show(int)

Yes. You convert it to a `char`

```
show(static_cast<char>(65));
```

or convert it using a "*function-style cast*" fashion.

```
show(char(65));
```

*Note: This will work **only** if your environment uses ASCII, because C++ does not mandate ASCII encoding for characters. Though systems using a different encoding are rare.*

Comment: Would *"function-style cast"* be the phrase you're after ?

Comment: @Quentin, Ahh yes. Thanks! fixed.

Comment: `show(static_cast<char>(65));` what does this static cast mean and what is a function style cast ?

Comment: @Anjaneyulu - Comments aren't the place for an introduction. [Pick a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try by creating variable with char type and u can pass it to Show function.

Ex :

```
char test = 'Z';

Show(test);
```

It will works!

Comment: the ascii encoding of `'Z'` is not `65`.

Comment: I dont think he was receiving 65 output for 'Z'.

He mentioned there at the end of the post like " show(65) to print the ASCII equivalent value 'A' "

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work because:

1. You already have a function which takes a number as an argument.
2. You have to manually convert it to char:`show(char(65))`.
3. Even if you convert it to char, it would only work if you're in an environment which uses ASCII (it's not the only encoding system in C++).

If you already know what char you want you can simply do this:

```
show('A');
```